# how to pass values to struct variable then write the struct in a file?

Tags: c, file, struct, segmentation-fault, fwrite

How can I pass values to struct variable I'm trying to get the employee information from the user then write them in a file, but I got a `segmentation fault` after entering employee name.
This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record_em{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int salary;
    int age;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct record_em employee;
    FILE *fp;
    int id, salary, age;
    char name[20];
    int n=1;

    fp = fopen("empRecord.dat","a");
    while(n==1){
        printf("\nEnter Employee ID\n");
        scanf("%d",&id);
        employee.id=id;
        printf("\nEnter Employee Name\n");
        scanf("%s",name);
        employee.name=name;
        printf("\nEnter Employee Salary\n");
        scanf("%d",&salary);
        employee.salary=salary;
        printf("\nEnter Employee Age\n");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        employee.age=age;
        fwrite(&employee,sizeof(employee),1,fp);
        printf("Enter 1 to add new record \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
    }
```

Output (taken from comment):

```
Fatmahs-MacBook-Air:~ fatmah$ gcc -o em em.c
Fatmahs-MacBook-Air:~ fatmah$ ./em
Enter Employee ID
88
Enter Employee Name
uu
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: I don't understand how a segmentation fault can occur as this should not complile: `employee.name=name;`. Is this the _exact_ code?

Comment: yes, `Fatmahs-MacBook-Air:~ fatmah$ gcc -o em em.c
Fatmahs-MacBook-Air:~ fatmah$ ./em

Enter Employee ID
88

Enter Employee Name
uu
Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/3JvSwG for _error: incompatible types in assignment_ compiler failure message.

Comment: Take a little look [Comparing and checking columns in two files][1]: 




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438941/comparing-and-checking-columns-in-two-files/13440245#13440245

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%s",name);
employee.name=name;
```

to

```
scanf("%s",name);
strcpy(employee.name, name);
```

Of, better still, as suggested by Dukeling & hmjd

```
scanf("%19s", employee.name);
```

Comment: How about just `scanf("%s", employee.name)`? Careful of buffer overflow.

Comment: Better again: `scanf("%19s", employee.name);` to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: What gets written to file?  Are you reading the file using a text or hex editor?  Remember that the ints you write will be written as 4 bytes and won't be rendered as a number in a text editor.  And that the name will have some text, then a nul (char code 0) character, then some uninitialised data.

Comment: and the hex editor in the left side shows hex number and in the right side only the name shows to me 1

Comment: @fatimah You've created a simple form of binary file.  Ints in this will be represented as 4 bytes (characters); these bytes often won't have a value that maps to a printable character in your text editor.  You'll only be able to sensibly view the contents in a hex editor.  If you don't understand the form of the data in the file, an alternative way to verify it would be to write a small program which does something like `fread(&employee,sizeof(employee),1,fp)` then prints out the fields of 'employee'.

Comment: hmmm what about convert them to char before writing them ?

Comment: @fatimah Try `fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d\n", employee.id, employee.name, employee.salary, employee.age)` in place of your `fwrite` line if you want to create a plain text file

Comment: @simonc if i want to modify a record according to employee id can i use fscanf to read the records and fprintf to rewrite it ?

Comment: @simonc 

`fp = fopen("empRecord.dat","rb+");

printf("Enter Id Number:\n");

scanf("%d",&n);

while (!feof(fp))

    {

fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d", &employee.id, employee.name,&employee.salary, &employee.age);

if (employee.id==n){

//take the new information for editing 

}

fseek(fp,-sizeof(employee),SEEK_CUR);

fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %d\n", employee.id, employee.name,employee.salary, employee.age);

exit(0);`

it writes the edited record as a new record at the end of the file, and when i use fwrite i face the same problem that happened yesterday.

Comment: It'd be easiest to answer this if you post a new question - its not too easy reading code in comments fields

Answer (score 3):

Here is one major problem:

```
scanf("%s",name);
employee.name=name;
```

The member `name` is an *array*, you can't assign to it. Instead use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to *copy* to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create** a typedef struct `record_t`to make the things shorter and easier to understand.

   ```
   typedef struct {
       int id;
       char name[20];
       int salary;
       int age;
   } record_t;
   ```
2. **Create** the file and format it first.

   ```
   void file2Creator( FILE *fp )
   {
       int i; // Counter to create the file.
       record_t data = { 0, "", 0, 0 }; // A blank example to format the file.

       /* You will create 100 consecutive records*/
       for( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ){
           fwrite( &data, sizeof( record_t ), 1, fp );
       }

       fclose( fp ); // You can close the file here or later however you need.  
   }
   ```
3. Write the function to **fill** the file.

   ```
   void fillFile( FILE *fp )
   {
       int position;
       record_t data = { 0, "", 0, 0 };


       printf( "Enter the position to fill (1-100) 0 to finish:\n?" );
       scanf( "%d", &position );

       while( position != 0 ){
           printf( "Enter the id, name, and the two other values (integers):\n?" );
           fscanf( stdin, "%d%s%d%d", &data.id, data.name, data.salary, data.age );

           /* You have to seek the pointer. */
           fseek( fp, ( position - 1 ) * sizeof( record_t ), SEEK_SET );
           fwrite( &data, sizeof( record_t ), 1, fp );
           printf( "Enter a new position (1-100) 0 to finish:\n?" );
           scanf( "%d", &position );
       }

       fclose( fPtr ); //You can close the file or not, depends in what you need.
   }
   ```

You can use this as reference [Comparing and checking columns in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438941/comparing-and-checking-columns-in-two-files/13440245#13440245)